# PHP Reverse the order of results from MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I want to reverse the order of the array.

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notfi1 WHERE Own='" .$_GET['u']. "'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo 'link:<a href=member.php?u=' .$row['UserId']. '>text</a><br>';
  }
```

Output:

```
<a href=member.php?u=name8>text</a>
<a href=member.php?u=name9>text</a>
<a href=member.php?u=name10>text</a>
```

and I want to reverse it:

```
<a href=member.php?u=name10>text</a>
<a href=member.php?u=name9>text</a>
<a href=member.php?u=name8>text</a>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two solutions:

1. Sort your links descending
2. Use array_reverse or rsort

Solution #1:

```
"SELECT * FROM notfi1 WHERE Own='" .$_GET['u']. "' ORDER BY UserId DESC"
```

Solution #2:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notfi1 WHERE Own='" .$_GET['u']. "'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[] = $row['UserId'];
}
rsort($data);
foreach($data as $item){
    echo 'link:<a href=member.php?u=' .$row['UserId']. '>text</a><br>';
}
```

Second method is better because it means you are seperating your data retrieval from your display... IT SHOULD be done this way but doesn't prevent you to sort your data on the MySQL Server

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show newest ID's first just sorty by user id

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notfi1 WHERE Own='" .$_GET['u']. "' ORDER BY UserId DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 'link:<a href=member.php?u=' .$row['UserId']. '>text</a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an `ORDER BY UserId DESC` to the SQL and let the database do it for you:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notfi1 WHERE Own='" .$_GET['u']. "' ORDER BY UserID DESC");
```

---

Side notes:

With that code you'd darn better pray nobody ever goes to `yoururl.com/yourpage.php?u='%20OR%201%3D1%20--` or worse. I suggest you read up on SQL injection attacks.

And if this is not old code you're modifying, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions in the first place. They're deprecated.

Comment: my code is example, my real code is checking if isnumbric and im using htmlspcialchars

Comment: Just use PDO to do queries, no need for htmlspecialchars.