# Reverse the array in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to reverse the array so that it could show newer entries in the database first then the older ones. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    include_once('db/connection.php');
        $query="select * from news";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
?>
<?php
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            ?>
                <div class="container">
                <div class="cust_bloglistintro">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 cust_blogteaser" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin-bottom: 32px;height: 750px;">
                         <div class="card" data-aos="fade-up" style="height: 700px;"><img class="card-img-top w-100 d-block" src="images/<?php echo $rows['thumbnail'];?>">
                        <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $rows['title']; ?> </h4><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $rows['date']; ?></span>
                                        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $rows['description']; ?></p><a class="card-link" href="<?php echo $rows['link']; ?>" target="_top">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: add ORDER BY to your SQL query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Reverse the order of results from MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842804/php-reverse-the-order-of-results-from-mysql-db)

Comment: Idk maybe `array_reverse()`?!??!??!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use ORDER BY clause of MySQL in your query.

select * from news ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `ORDER BY` clause in your query which will save you tons of time and effort.
If you want the result to be in descending. Try the code below.

```
select * from news ORDER BY id DESC
```

or if you want the result to be in ascending.

```
select * from news ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem.